# how to design a gridview dynamically with rows and columns android?

Tags: android

i am really new in android and java. please give a suggestion to me. In my application after parsed the json i got maxrows and maxcolumns. based on this rows and columns i will create a view with images. If maxrows are 14 and maxcols are 5, put the images based on condition on view. Every time condition will be change.

Activity:

```
    package com.app.redbuslayout;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView grid;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    String maxrows;
    int maxcol;
    int[] imageId = {
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat ,R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,
              R.drawable.seat,

              R.drawable.seat,
              };

              @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, imageId);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // define the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

         grid =new GridView(MainActivity.this);

         grid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         grid.setNumColumns(maxcol);



         grid.setAdapter(adapter);
         relativeLayout.addView(grid);

            // set the RelativeLayout as our content view
            setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutParams);

        new GetRoute().execute("http://sb2.reloadit.in/TravelServices.asmx/Getlayout");
    }

     private     class GetRoute extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
            /*String mJourneyDate;
            public GetData(String pJourneyDate) {
                this.mJourneyDate = pJourneyDate;
            }*/ProgressDialog pd = null;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
                }

                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String response;

                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RouteScheduleID","428205707"));

                         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JourneyDate","2014-12-16"));


                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                        HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                        HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

                        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                        Log.d("response is", response);

                        return new JSONObject(response);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
                {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //Log.v("TAG_RESULTadapter",""+result);

                    pd.dismiss();
                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("Response");
                            String message = jobj.getString("Message");
                            String issuceess = jobj.getString("IsSuccess");

                            if(issuceess.equals("true"))
                            {

                                JSONObject layout = result.getJSONObject("Layout");  
                                // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+layoutarray);
                                  maxrows=layout.getString("MaxRows");
                                  maxcol=layout.getInt("MaxColumns");
                                /* Log.v("TAG_maxrows",""+maxrows);
                                    Log.v("TAG_Maxcol",""+maxcol);*/
                                    JSONArray routearray = layout.getJSONArray("SeatDetails");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {

                                     String Row = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Row");
                                 // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+Row);
                                     String Col = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Col");
                                     String Height = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Height");
                                  String  Width = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Width");
                                     String SeatNo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SeatNo");
                                  String Gender = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Gender");

                                         String Deck = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Deck");
                                         String IsAvailable = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsAvailable");
                                      String  Fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");
                                     Log.v("TAG_Maxfare",""+Fare);

                                    }

                            }
                        }


                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
}
}



    adapter class:

            package com.app.redbuslayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    private final int[] Imageid;
      public CustomGrid(Context c,int[] Imageid ) {
          mContext = c;
          this.Imageid = Imageid;

      }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return Imageid.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View grid;
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
          } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
          }



      return grid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create grid view dynamically like this,you can set dynamical values for rows and columns in this

```
// create a gridview
GridView gridView= new GridView(this);

gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
gridView.setNumColumns(set number of columns here);
gridView.setColumnWidth(GridView.AUTO_FIT);  
gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);  
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: max rows 14 and cols 5 but every time condition will be changed

Comment: set Number of columns what you want. that will calculate how many rows required to fill the grid view. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: based on one condition if i want 5 columns. then how will i get 14  rows. sorry i m nt clear

Comment: see, first you will know how many columns you want.. after that create grid view with that number. It will calculate about rows no need to mention about the rows here.

Comment: setNumColumns only  allows int value. i dont  know how to add the maxrow value to setNumColumn

Comment: Convert string value to int and set there.. and set number of columns first...code will calculate the rows.

Comment: ha i converted to int and set as setNumColumns(maxcol); but it is not working

Comment: post your full code in the question .. will help to resolve the issue.